# X In Top Left Corner of Popover / Modal iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I got this image in a design, and I'm not sure how to implement the X button in the top left corner. This needs to be a `UIViewController` presented with `modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet`, or `modalPresentationStyle = .popover`, not just a `UIView`. How do I get the X button to be outside the modal/popover bounds, as well as still take touch events? I would strongly prefer a 'clean' solution that is not too complicated to implement, or would feel hacky.

[image]

Comment: Any reason for downvote / close? Is this answered somewhere else on SO?  - How is this unclear? Drawing outside the modal view controller's bounds is not trivial, is it?

Comment: You can set the clipsToBounds on the view controller's content view to false and the button will be drawn, but I'm not sure about being able to click outside the view bounds. (And it seems like a reasonable question to me.)

Comment: Seems like there is enough room on the screen to have the X button Inside the bounds of the modal. Just make sure the X button is on top of the other views.